# Change colour of SVG loaded from file

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have an SVG loaded from file in an  tag like so...

```
<img class="svgbutton" src="filepath/icon.svg">
```

the svg is just a simple icon in a single colour. Is it possible to control the colour of the svg in someway (possibly a filter?), either using css or javascript?

Or is the only proper way to do this to draw it fully in the script..?

Comment: There is an hack : https://gist.github.com/LeaVerou/5198257

Answer (score 4):

This can require some Javascript or Jquery, often a bit tricky.

The simpliest way that I can think about that may work is this **CSS** **code:**

```
.element {
    -webkit-mask: url(yourimage.svg) center / contain no-repeat;
    background: red;
}
```

However, some browers do not support this, there are fallbacks though.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use inline SVG like this in HTML:

```
<div style="color: red;">
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        [ ... ]
    </svg>
</div>
```

By doing so you may use standard CSS (and JavaScript if required for dynamic changes, but keep in mind that there are pseudo-classes to style mouse-over and much more). The trick here is to apply the inherited CSS `color` to the SVG fill color with `fill: currentColor;`

```
<style type="text/css">
    svg {
        fill: currentColor;
    }
</style>
```

You could also keep multiple symbols together, hide thie whole "collection" with CSS `display: none;` on the `<svg ...>` element and reuse the symbols separately in multiple places.

A symbol definition in the "collection":

```
<g id="icon1">
    <path class="path1" d="M22 20c-2 2-2 4-4 4s-4-2-6-4-4-4-4-6 2-2 4-4-4-8-6-8-6 6-6 6c0 4 4.109 12.109 8 16s12 8 16 8c0 0 6-4 6-6s-6-8-8-6z"></path>
</g>
```

Use it anywhere like this:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 64 64">
    <use xlink:href="#icon1"></use>
</svg>
```

*NOTE: `xlink:href` is deprecated as of SVG 2.0 and is being replaced by `href` which might not yet be supported by your browser though...*

You could also color multiple paths in one symbol differently:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .path1 {
        color: blue;
        fill: currentColor;
    }
</style>
```

Keep experimenting with classes and [pseudo-classes](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp) before choosing JavaScript for dynamically changing your element's classes as it might not be necessary.

Comment: I may not be understanding your answer correctly but i'm not sure that this actually answers my question... where does the filepath go to link to the external svg?

Comment: I'm trying to show you, how it's possible to use CSS for SVG elements, as contents in embedded objects (with `<img ...>` or `<object ...>` cannot be styled by your document (just within that object, therefore not changeable by the document that displays the image).

The filepath goes in the same attribute, e.g.

`<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100"><use xlink:href="/images/defs.svg#icon"></use></svg>`

... where `#icon` is the id of a symbol. If you leave the id, the whole SVG will be used.

Comment: Styling SVG in more detail:

https://css-tricks.com/svg-use-external-source/ and 
https://css-tricks.com/cascading-svg-fill-color/

Comment: 1. inline svg cannot be reused over project
2. browser will not cash inline svg
3. it's difficult to manage svg icons if you are going to choose them dynamically (e.g. by user choice)